# TypeScript 4.9 error (can`t use satisfies)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dependencies, syntax-error, version

Why after npm install -g typescript@latest (for lates version at 2022.12 - 4.9v) i can`t use satisfies?
Error ... ! (error: Newline or semicolon expected)
At the package.json
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "^4.9.4"
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WcXI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erJVs.png)

Comment: Do you have an error in your console or IDE? it looks like your IDE using older version of TS

Comment: This is IDE error. But i can`t understand what the problem (you can see problem at the screenshot)

Comment: Just change the version of TS in your IDE config

Comment: i checked my IDE config. IDE using lates version of TS . @captain-yossarian from Ukraine

Comment: maybe you can update eslint typescript too